# How to customise googlemap infoWindow using Swift 3

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, infowindow

Xcode version:
8.1

aim:

To replace native infoWindow by custom one

problem:

1. When I click on the marker, my custom infoWindow did not show up but the native one,
   Or
2. Thread 1:signal SIGABRT shown if I don't delete `myView.delegate = self`(See my code & my research #21)

what I have done:

1. Created a .swift file and a .xib file with my custom infoWindow design.
2. Inserted mapView function into ViewController.swift:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   ```

   ...

   ```
       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude,
                                             longitude: Longitude, zoom: 16)
       let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
       mapView.delegate = self  // Thread 1:signal SIGABRT shown if i add this line
       mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
       self.view = mapView

       let marker = GMSMarker()
       marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, Longitude)
       marker.title = "Me"
       marker.map = mapView
       mapView.selectedMarker = marker
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
       let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! CustomInfoWindow
       infoWindow.title.text = marker.title
       return infoWindow
   }
   ```

my research:

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p
3. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8462
4. http://kevinxh.github.io/swift/custom-and-interactive-googlemaps-ios-sdk-infowindow.html
5. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/w0sP7r3XAF4
6. [Custom InfoWindow for marker Google Maps SDK, Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488506/custom-infowindow-for-marker-google-maps-sdk-swift-2-0)
7. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY
8. [Custom annotation view in Google Maps SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267183/custom-annotation-view-in-google-maps-sdk)
9. [Creating custom info window in swift with the Google maps iOS sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462187/creating-custom-info-window-in-swift-with-the-google-maps-ios-sdk)
10. [How to show a Info window in iOS Google maps without tapping on Marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816684/how-to-show-a-info-window-in-ios-google-maps-without-tapping-on-marker)
11. [Custom info window in IOS google maps sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599791/custom-info-window-in-ios-google-maps-sdk)
12. [IOS Google Map Custom InfoWindow Xib error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748622/ios-google-map-custom-infowindow-xib-error)
13. [Google Maps Info window's resizing based on the internal content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643740/google-maps-info-windows-resizing-based-on-the-internal-content)
14. [Custom Info Window for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps)
15. [Custom InfoWindows issue -Google Maps iOS SDK-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694740/custom-infowindows-issue-google-maps-ios-sdk)
16. [How to customize the InfoWindow of google map iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177712/how-to-customize-the-infowindow-of-google-map-ios-sdk)
17. [swift 3 google maps custom infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927022/swift-3-google-maps-custom-infowindow)
18. [How to initialise a UIView Class with a xib file in Swift, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513271/how-to-initialise-a-uiview-class-with-a-xib-file-in-swift-ios)
19. https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMaps-Swift/blob/master/GoogleMapSwift/ViewController.swift
20. https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/GoogleMapsCalloutView
21. [Implementing custom markerInfoWindow in swift not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292330/implementing-custom-markerinfowindow-in-swift-not-working?rq=1)
22. https://codedump.io/share/hh7CO7c2j3PI/1/custom-infowindow-for-marker-google-maps-sdk-swift-20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you implement GMSMapViewDelegate?

```
ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

   ...

}
```

It seems to be that you are getting the error(crash) because you are setting the delegate to self, but your controller does not conform to that protocol.